# How to fix a circular dependency

Tags: architecture, dependency-injection, architectural-patterns

I have a `IItemProcessor` class which takes each item from a list and send it to a web API (`IApiService`). The processing is done asynchronously, on another thread.

If web API responds with 'user not authorized', app needs to logout. For this, I have an `IApp` which has `LogoutUser()` method.

Currently, the `ItemProcessor` implementation catches errors thrown by `IApiService` and if the error is 'not authorized', it calls `IApp:LogoutUser`.

The issue is in the implementation of `IApp:LogoutUser` I need to call `IItemProcessor:Stop` to stop processing. Which means there's a circular dependency between `App` and `ItemProcessor.

I'm using Dependency Injection in the c-tor and this gives me infinite recursive construction of the concrete objects:

```
public class App : IApp 
{
   public App(IItemProcessor itemProcessor)
   {
    ...
   }

   public void Logout() 
   {
       _itemProcessor.Stop(); 
   }
}

public class ItemProcessor : IItemProcessor 
{
    public ItemProcessor (IApp app)
    {
      ...
    }

    public void Stop() {
      ...
    }

    void Run() 
    {
        ... for each item in list ..
         try
         {
            ... try send item ....
         }
         catch(UserNotAuthorizedException)
         {
             _app.Logout();
         }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

`IApp` needs to know about `IItemProcessor` to start and stop it on user login and logut. But I feel like `IItemProcessor` breaks SRP, it shouldn't actually call `Logout`, but rather somehow inform "someone" about the error, and that "someone" has in turn the responsability to call `IApp:LogoutUser`. But what should this "someone" be? Should it be a listener to the item processor errors?

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to split responsibilities.

I tried to use command pattern by having a `LogoutCommand`

```
public class LogoutCommand
{
    readonly IApp _app;

    public LogoutCommand(IApp app)
    {
        _app = app;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _app.UserLogout();
    }
}
```

the `ItemProcessor` implementation could call `logoutCommand.Execute()`. 
This would decouple `ItemProcessor` from knowing about `App`, but I have the same issue because when `App` c-tor calls `ItemProcessor` c-tor which calls `LogoutCommand` which calls `App` c-tor.

Another (bad) idea: I thought a factory could alleviate this issue. I thought having a `ILogoutCommandFactory` factory which creates the `LogoutCommand`. As long as I didn't create the `LogoutCommand` in the c-tor of `ItemProcessor`, I thought it could work. But the fact that I can't do that, feels to me like code smell.

To me DI in c-tor seems to start looking like an issue.

Comment: Does App tell IItemProcessor to process?  Catch the notauthorized exception from the code the calls Run and call logout then.  Alternately you can have a NotAuthorized event on the IItemProcessor interface.  App hooks into it and calls Logout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, there is no cyclic dependency. When I understood you correctly, `App` depends on the interface `IItemProcessor`, and not on its implementation `ItemProcessor`. Also, `ItemProcessor` depends on `IApp`, and not on `App`. However, you will need to switch to property injection for at least one of the classes, this will look like

```
public class App : IApp 
{
   public App(IItemProcessor itemProcessor)
   {
      itemProcessor.TheApp = this;
   }
}

public class ItemProcessor : IItemProcessor 
{
    public ItemProcessor ()
    {
      ...
    }

    public IApp TheApp{get;set;}

}
```

However, to decouple your components even more, or if your DI framework still has problems with this, `IApp` could provide a publisher/subscriber mechanism (AKA [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)) for something like a "BeforeLogout" event. In a similar manner, `IItemProcessor` could provide a publisher/subscriber mechanism for "not authorized" events it gets from the `IApiService`. For example, in C# this could look like

```
interface IItemProcessor
{
    void SubscribeToUserNotAuthorized(Action<Exception> observer);
}
```

and

```
public ItemProcessor() : IItemProcessor
{
    List<Action<Exception>> notAuthorizedObservers;

    public void SubscribeToUserNotAuthorized(Action<Exception> observer)
    {
        notAuthorizedObservers.Add(observer);
    }

    // and somewhere below

    // ...
         catch(NotAuthorizedException ex)
         {
            foreach(var observer in notAuthorizedObservers)
               observer(ex);
         }
}
```

Comment: ninja'ed.  pub/sub observer is something i have use in the past and was typing up a reply with.

Comment: I edited my question. Issue is I am using DI in c-tor which gives me infinite creation of the objects.

Comment: What does "technically" mean? If technically there is no cyclic dependency, why does the DI gets in the way? I feel like cyclic dependency is a sign of bad design. Like I mentioned, I think in my case, the processor shouldn't know to call logout, it breaks SRP. Or maybe it doesn't? HELP! :)

Comment: I edited it again. I tried to use command pattern but with same result.

Comment: @DonBox: see my edit.

Comment: @DocBrown I really appreciate it but I don't think DI by setter is a good way of solving my issue. AFAIK setter-injection is when you have a default for dependency which you allow to be changed. Which is definitely not my case here.

Comment: Thanks. I wish we could discussed and found better ideas/solutions. But thanks again for replying, it's been very helpful to me.